# Not able to change radio button value in webdriver

Tags: html, selenium

In this html code, cash is selected as default and I want to change radio value as card.

```
<label>
    <input id="cash" type="radio" checked="" value="CS" name="cash_cash">
    <i></i>CASH
</label>
<label>
    <input id="card" type="radio" value="CD" name="cash_cash">
    <i></i>Card
</label>
```

I have used below codes, none of them gave me results.

METHOD 1

```
WebElement pl=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='cash_cash'and @value='card']"));
pl.click();
```

METHOD 2

```
List<WebElement> radiobuttons = driver.findElements(By.id("card"));
for(WebElement radio:radiobuttons)
{
    String cvalue = radio.getAttribute("value");
    if(cvalue .equals("CD"))
    {
        radio.click();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("fails");
    }
}

int rcount = radiobuttons.size();
```

Above line gives me `rcount` as 4 although there are only two options.

please help me with this (its a pop-up).
[HTML source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJw9l.png)

Comment: It is very weird that  `rcount` is 4. Does the application assign duplicate id to elements?

Comment: That page having only two radio buttons,i hve checked html code there is no duplicate name,its a popup screen! is it reflecting the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    First select xpath of radio button which you want to select,then use click(), enable it and display by using isEnabled and isDisplayed
```

Thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='payment_add_form']/div/div[1]/h3/span/div[2]/label/i")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression in method 1 is incorrect. It should be `@id='card'` instead of `@value='card'`. See code below:

**Solution 1**: By.xpath

```
List<WebElement> radiobuttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='cash_cash'and @id='card']"));
for(WebElement radio:radiobuttons)
{
    if(radio.isDisplayed()){
        radio.click();
        break;
    }   
}
```

**Solution 2**: By.cssSelector

```
List<WebElement> radiobuttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input#card[value='CD']"));
for(WebElement radio:radiobuttons)
{
    if(radio.isDisplayed()){
        radio.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ksingh Could you give me the screenshot of your popup and full HTML code of your application?

Comment: As you told its duplicating "name"  its in hide,how can i avoid it?

Comment: @Ksingh The `name` is not duplicated. You can assign the same name to multiple elements. But I did told you that `id` is duplicated, the id must be unique.

Comment: @Ksingh I've added another solution which use cssSelector. Could you try it?

Comment: I've update the answer to check isDisplayed() before click(). Could you try again?

Comment: Yeah i have tried,that radio value not selecting card.Iam trying from last 23 hours for this task.

Comment: i have used radio.getAttribute("value").IsSelected() with in the for loop, but this too not working,